# How to divide a column by few other sub columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need to convert the following python code into pyspark.

```
df['GRN_ratio'] = df['GRN Quantity']/ df.groupby(['File No','Delivery Note Number'])['GRN 
                  Quantity'].transform(sum)
```

For that I am using following Pyspark code.But I am not getting the expected output.

```
df.groupby(['File No','Delivery Note Number']).agg(F.sum('GRN Quantity').alias('GRN_Sum')))
           .withColumn("GRN_ratio", F.col("GRN Quantity")/F.col("GRN_Sum"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function instead of group by:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn('GRN_ratio',
    F.col('GRN Quantity') / 
    F.sum('GRN Quantity').over(Window.partitionBy('File No','Delivery Note Number'))
)
```